# Google Map API v2 inflator fails on old phones

Tags: android, google-maps-mobile

I have just implemented a map in the application, and it runs flawlessly in a Galaxy S3. Testing my app with an old phone HTC Sense with API8 the app throws a inflator problem. I think it may be related to either the OS or OGL2. isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) returns a correct value. Help me here, please:

Activity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
 @Override
 public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.initializeInterface();
 }

 private void initializeInterface() {
    final int available = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
 }
}
```

main.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@id/header" />
```

manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.stuff.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.stuff.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/application_name" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/map_api_key_device"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Error

```
12-13 12:14:13.865: E/My ERROR(22878): Binary XML file line #85: Error inflating class fragment
12-13 12:14:13.875: E/android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(22878): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
12-13 12:14:13.895: E/android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(22878): at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
12-13 12:14:13.915: E/android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(22878): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
12-13 12:14:13.915: E/android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(22878): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-13 12:14:13.935: E/android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(22878): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-13 12:14:13.945: E/com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(22878): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
12-13 12:14:13.945: E/android.app.Activity.setContentView(22878): at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1654)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with the fact that you are trying to use native API Level 11 fragments on an API Level 8 device. Switch to `FragmentActivity` and `SupportMapFragment` if you wish to have your code work on earlier versions than Android 3.0.

Comment: I added the support library with rightclick, Android->Add Support Library... 

It extended the problem to the S3 too :/

Comment: @EfEs: You will not get `Error inflating class fragment` from an S3 using `FragmentActivity` to load the layout.

Comment: It shouldn't, yet it does :(

12-13 14:36:36.424: W/dalvikvm(7301): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1115 (common_google_play_services_install_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;

Comment: There's a problem with the XML parsing so I just did it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding the v13 libraries from /extras/android/compatibility/v13 and changing my Activity to FragmentActivity and MapFragment to SupportMapFragment.

Answer (score 0):

for me help  app project -> right click -> properties -> android -> project build target -> and chack earlier android release. (with google api)

if you dont have, download one by `SDK manager`