# Error retrieving SupportMapFragment's GoogleMap member when added programmatically

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

After having some parsing problems [inflating the XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859059/google-map-api-v2-inflator-fails-on-old-phones) I decided to do a programmatic workaround. The map is correctly added to the scene, but I have problems caching it as a class member for later usage. Here is the code snippet with the explosion point.

Activity:

```
public class MoogliActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
  final SupportMapFragment supportMap = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
  final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = this.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.maplayout, supportMap);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
 mGoogleMap = supportMap.getMap(); // mGoogleMap = null after this
 // mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); Obviously NullPointerException
}

}
```

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/maplayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tracking"
    android:layout_below="@id/header" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

`mGoogleMap = supportMap.getMap()`;

Should be called after onCreate. Try onResume(), like this.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // here it should work
    mGoogleMap = supportMap.getMap(); 

    // In case Google Play services has since become available.
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}
```